# Declare static and non-static variable

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I declared a public static string and I put the variable inside the function to know the status of my sync. My problem is the variable won't overwrite. I know it is a static variable. I dont know how to overwrite the variable or declare a non-static variable inside the **public static async void** so that I will know what is the status of my sync. I will display the status in my xaml.

```
public class SyncFunction
{
    public static string status; //This will display status of every function below

    public static async void SyncUser(string host, string database, string contact, string ipaddress, byte[] pingipaddress){
      ... // Function here
      status = "Syncing user";
    }

    public static async void SyncHost(string host, string database, string contact, string ipaddress, byte[] pingipaddress){
      ... // Function here
      status = "Syncing host";
    }

}
```

In my XAML.CS will be:

```
lblStatus.text = SyncFunction.status; //will display the status of my sync
```

Comment: How often are you executing that last statement? It will only assign the current value once. You might need to set up a dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the default value of **status**(string) in your code is *null*, which *lblStatus* will treat as *String.Empty*.

You have to call **SynUser** or **SyncHost** before trying to display **status** in your view (xaml).

Hope this helps.